# highlight the regular expression java

Tags: java, regex

I want to highlight the matching words in text using Java. I made the application, but for some reason the code below is not working. Can someone tell me what's going on? Thanks.

```
    pattern = Pattern.compile(txt1.getText());
    matcher = pattern.matcher( ""+txtarea1.getText());



    while (matcher.find())
    {
        txtarea2.setText( txtarea1.getText());
    }
    matcher.group();

    Highlighter h = txtarea2.getHighlighter();
    HighlightPainter painter = 
         new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.YELLOW);



 int p0 = matcher.start();
 int p1 = matcher.end();
    try {
       h.addHighlight(p0, p1, painter);
   } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(RE.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
```

`

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?

Comment: is there any exception or you get wrong output?

Comment: What behavior are you seeing?

Comment: yeah , and the result was like this 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found

Comment: Have you read tutorial about Pattern/Matcher classes? What do you expect `matcher.group();` to return when `while (matcher.find())` will finally be evaluated to `false`?

Comment: to be honest with you , no i didn't read about Pattren/Matcher classes , the teacher gives us a homework and he didn't say anything about matcher/pattren classes , i made the application on my previous knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You're skipping over the found text.

```
while (matcher.find())
{
    txtarea2.setText( txtarea1.getText());
}
```

Let's say there is a match in the middle of the text.  The first time `find` is true you'll set the text on `txtarea2`.  Now we go to the top of the loop and `find` is called again.  The positions of `start` and `end` are now passed the found text so you won't get the correct indexes from

```
int p0 = matcher.start();
int p1 = matcher.end();
```

In fact, I tested this flow and actually get an exception.  Here's the test code:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("a");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("bbbbbbbabbbbbb");

    while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("Found!");
    }

    System.out.println("start = " + matcher.start());
    System.out.println("end = " + matcher.end());
```

Here's the output (line 23 is the call to `matcher.end()`)

```
Found!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match available
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.start(Matcher.java:343)
    at com.conan.faker.Bar.main(Bar.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: so the problem at matcher.end() , or i must  change the whole code

Comment: You'll have to rearrange the code so that you are getting highlighted sections correctly.